# How can I add Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second to mysql date using date_add?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is the best way to add to a datetime type column in mysql database? I tried using DATE_ADD but it only works when I add single date/time like:

```
DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL :dayCount DAY)
```

This does NOT Work:

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL :dayCount DAY), INTERVAL :hourCount HOUR)
```

I tried adding microseconds as suggested by some:

```
$startMicro = strtotime($startDiff->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")) * 1000; // 943920000000
start=DATE_ADD(start, INTERVAL :startMicro MICROSECOND)
```

I DID THIS IN THE END AND IT WORKS:
in PHP:
    $minutesDiff = (strtotime($start) - strtotime($row->start)) / 60;
in SQL STATEMENT:
    start=DATE_ADD(start, INTERVAL :minutesDiff MINUTE)

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Hi, the better approach is to add MICROSECOND, just convert you amount of time to microseconds and add it

Comment: @Dan Bracuk:
why? is that the only way it's a few columns and also do I have to create a complete query for each or do I just write down the function over and over. Show me an example please if you could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the total time being added to the smallest increment of time you want to add, so rather than 1 day, 1 hour, you'd do 25 hours.  Instead of 1 hour, 1 minute, 1 second, you'd do 3601 seconds, etc.

You can nest them if desired, but your syntax is incorrect, missing a comma before 2nd `INTERVAL`, should be:

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL :dayCount DAY), INTERVAL :hourCount HOUR)
```

Comment: I tried adding microseconds but makes the database value 0000-00-00 00:00:00  
  $startMicro = strtotime($startDiff->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")) * 1000;
    start=DATE_ADD(start, INTERVAL :startMicro MICROSECOND)

Comment: No need to go below the lowest unit that you actually intend to add.

Comment: still the same for minutes maybe my conversion is off. How to convert datetime to minutes then? Thanks for all your help btw.

Comment: in the end I did this and it works.  
in PHP:
$minutesDiff = (strtotime($start) - strtotime($row->start)) / 60;
in the sql:  
start=DATE_ADD(start, INTERVAL :minutesDiff MINUTE)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax for the purpose:

```
start_date + INTERVAL :dayCount DAY + 
             INTERVAL :hourCount HOUR + 
             INTERVAL :minCount MINUTE
```

The INTERVAL types are YEAR, QUARTER, MONTH, WEEK, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, and MICROSECOND.

Microseconds don't make any sense with MySQL versions before 5.6.4.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add